# How to show whether a function is in BV$[0,1]$ or is in BV?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Determine whether the following function is in BV$[0,1]$ or is in BV (where BV denotes Bounded Variation).
$$f(x)=x^2.$$
I have verified that Total Variation $Tf(1)-Tf(0)=1$.  $f$ is monotonic increasing on $[0,1]$ and $|f'(x)\leq 2|$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.  Therefore, $f(x)$ is in BV$[0,1]$.  However, I am not able to verified whether $f$ is in BV.

Comment: By $BV$ do you mean $BV(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Hint: what is the total variation of $f$ over $(-n, n)$? Pass $n$ to infinity.